# FormHelper::getSourceValue() doesn't return entity on validation errors in CakePHP4

Tags: php, cakephp-4.x

I have an entity `article` that contains entities `photos` with `hasMany` association.

When I edit the article, I use `$this->Form->getSourceValue('photos')` to get and display the associated photos of the field `photos` underneath the input file.

```
// $this->Form->getSourceValue('photos') when I arrive on edit page of an article
[
  (int) 0 => object(FileManager\Model\Entity\Fichier) id:0 {
    'id' => (int) 36
    'model' => 'Articles'
    'foreign_key' => (int) 190
    'field' => 'photos'
    'dir' => '/files/Articles/photos'
    'filename' => 'Photo1.png'
    'type' => 'image/png'
    'size' => (int) 1393814
    'caption' => ''
    'rang' => (int) 4294967295
    '[new]' => false
    '[accessible]' => [
      '*' => false,
      'caption' => true,
    ]
    '[dirty]' => [
    ]
    '[original]' => [
    ]
    '[virtual]' => [
    ]
    '[hasErrors]' => false
    '[errors]' => [
    ]
    '[invalid]' => [
    ]
    '[repository]' => 'FileManager.Photos'
  },
  (int) 1 => object(FileManager\Model\Entity\Fichier) id:1 {
    'id' => (int) 37
    'model' => 'Articles'
    'foreign_key' => (int) 190
    'field' => 'photos'
    'dir' => '/files/Articles/photos'
    'filename' => 'Photo2.png'
    'type' => 'image/png'
    'size' => (int) 1400345
    'caption' => ''
    'rang' => (int) 4294967295
    '[new]' => false
    '[accessible]' => [
      '*' => false,
      'caption' => true,
    ]
    '[dirty]' => [
    ]
    '[original]' => [
    ]
    '[virtual]' => [
    ]
    '[hasErrors]' => false
    '[errors]' => [
    ]
    '[invalid]' => [
    ]
    '[repository]' => 'FileManager.Photos'
  },
]
```

**My goal is to allow to write caption for associated photos**, so I display an input `caption` underneath each photo :

```
// Inputs for Associated Photos underneath each photo
$this->Form->control("$field.$i.id");
$this->Form->control("$field.$i.caption");
```

But when I have an validation error in the form for article then `getSourceValue('photos')` doesn't contain entities `photos` any more but an array with `id` and `caption` instead.

```
// $this->Form->getSourceValue('photos') after validation error
[
    [
        'id' => 36,
        'caption' => ''
    ],
    [
        'id' => 37,
        'caption' => ''
    ]
]
```

I can't display the photos any more.

How can I get the entities `photo` after validation fails ?

Answer (score 0):

The form helper will by default use the values from the request data in case present, so that your form is populated with the data entered by the user after it has been submitted, otherwise the data entered by the user could be lost, for example on validation errors, in which case the invalid data is not being set on the entity.

If you want to use data unrelated to what you're submitting, then you're usually best of to obtain it directly from the entity that you're using for the form instead, or, depending on the situation, from a separately queried entity, one that is never being touched by neither the form helper, nor the patching mechanism in the controller.

Long story short, use `$article->photos` instead of `$this->Form->getSourceValue('photos')`.

Comment: OK, but in my case I don't see how it can be possible.
In fact, I want to implement a method `UploaderHelper::control($fielName, $options)`.
So I would like in this method to display both file input and value (thumbmails + caption) of the images associated directly from the $fielName parameter.

Comment: @Oliv Pass the original entity to your helper as a dependency.

Comment: You mean add a parameter in the method `UploaderHelper::control($fieldName, $entity, $options)` ?

Comment: @Oliv Either something like that, or you could add a separate method for it to keep the entity across multiple `control()` calls, similar to how the form helper does with its `create()` method.